# Target :before and :after pseudo-elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, pseudo-element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

On pageload I want the :before and :after elements on a class to appear. I've set the .lifted:before and .lifted:after to be opacity:0 in the css. Within document ready I have:

```
$(".lifted:before").css("opacity", "1");
$(".lifted:after").css("opacity", "1");
```

This doesn't work. And the .after jQuery manipulator is only made for inserting content as far as I can tell.

Is there any way I can manipulate the css of these pseudo-elements using jQuery?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#Not_supported <- here are the docs <- you cannot

Answer (score 27):

Decided to go with the solution of adding a class on load to the element and then manipulating it in the css.

```
$(".lifted").addClass("on");
```

CSS

```
.lifted.on:before,
.lifted.on:after {
               opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1); 
         -o-transition: opacity 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1); 
            transition: opacity 1200ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
       -moz-transition: none /* Removed until FF4 hang bug is fixed */
```

Comment: +1 for an elegant solution. Adding a class instead of struggling to select a semi-existant element is very nice. Thank you.

Comment: But this doesn't address the issue of manipulating the 'before' content with jQuery.