# Can not insert css image into pseudo :before

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert a background image into a header:before element, but jquery fails.

**HTML**
     
       content

```
 <a href="image.jpg" class="image-source">Try insert image into .header:before</a>
```

**JS**

```
 $('.image-source').click(function() {
   var src = $(this).attr('href');
    // slash is okay
    $('.header:before').css('backgroundImage', 'url(/' + src + ')'); 
    return false;
 });
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  position: relative;
  background: url(anotherimage.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.header:before  {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  min-width:50%;
  min-height:50%;
  content: "";
}
```

Does anyone know if I am dealing with a bug here, or missed an obvious?
Note, I can not use `.header` itself, because I am working with multiple background image, thats why I need `:before`.

**UPDATE:** 
Might be this:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#x2
- [Target :before and :after pseudo-elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814810/target-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-jquery#comment6671974_5814824)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: have you tried just changing a class instead of setting the image directly?

Comment: Thanks, but no classes, I have many dynamic images

Comment: @Rob W, I don't think its a dup, thanks

Comment: @RobW that would be the case, but `content: url(attr(data-src));` is invalid & doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot manipulate Pseudo Elements using jQuery. They are not part of DOM. You might want to avoid ugly workaround for this as well.

One of the most ugliest but my best workaround is this

```
var css = '.image:after { content: url("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");  width: 400px; height: 100px; }';

$("#replaceable").html(css);
$("div").addClass('image');

$("div").click(function() {
    var css = '.image:after { content: url("http://www.google.com/logos/2012/elias_lonnrot-2012-hp.jpg");  width: 400px; height: 100px; }';
    $("#replaceable").html(css);
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/ssPHv/)

Comment: Yes, thanks, thats exactly what T.J. Crowder said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814810/target-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-jquery#comment6671974_5814824

Comment: @swan, Did I mention it is exactly what you need.

Comment: Still digesting. Sound more complicated than what I am trying to do.

Comment: @swan, There is no pleasing you, Is it?

Comment: Its good, thanks, but the additional markup id="replaceable" is defeating my clean markup. Still digesting

Comment: I accept the fact "You cannot manipulate Pseudo Elements using jQuery"

Answer (score 2):

you could insert the background image as straight content, instead of using javascript

```
.header:before  {
  ...
  content: url(...);
}
```

Comment: What if he needs to change the background programatically? This isn't an answer to the OPs problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to have fun with jquery. And I can not insert dynamic image using content, either

Answer (score 1):

I think your best best would be to do this:
css:

```
header.first:after{/* your image etc */}
header.second:after{/* your image etc */}
header.third:after{/* your image etc */}
```

then jQuery:

```
var headers = ["first","second","third"];
var i = 0;
$(".next").click(function(){
  i %= headers.length;
  $("header").removeClass(headers[i-1]).addClass(headers[i]);
  i++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds redundant with 20 images to play with :(

Comment: @swan, yeah, there's gotta be a better way, can't you add an element to your html? it'll be easier to change the BG image on an element that's actually in the DOM...

Comment: No, I am afraid. Its dynamic insertion of images for selection. Images are aggregated from one or two folders at different places, too. The unavoidable is images may grow to hundred overtime.

Comment: @swan I've reduced the redundancy in the JS... check it out, but if you have hundreds CSS doesn't seem like the best answer for this.

Comment: "can't you add an element to your html". This tricks me to do a reverse. .header is for Dynamic images, and .header:before for static dom. This doesn't solve the original question, but make the ball rolls. Thanks a lot