# Modify CSS psuedo selector style in sencha

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch

I am developing a web app in sencha touch. I need to dynamically change the style for one of the class with psuedo element.

Below is my element in the css file..

```
.testdiv::before{
    margin-left: -0.4em;
    margin-top: -0.10em;
 }
```

I need to change the margin-top values dynamically in the code as the style needs to be changed in different screens.

I tried

```
Ext.select(".testdiv").setStyle('margin-top','1em').
```

But this doesn't apply style to the psuedo element ": before".. How can I do this ?

Comment: No i don't want to add an additional framework just for this fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible even in jQuery, but I found a solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814810/target-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-jquery)

you need to add an extra class to your `testdiv` elements, e.g. `on` and add a css rule:

```
.testdiv.on:before {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Ext.select(".testdiv").addCls(".on") ??